# Update constrains based on condition

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I wanted to be able to update my view in a certain condition. For example, a coffee app with three labels side by side, one says the size of the cup, other the topping used and other the time taken to prepare. Imagine a certain coffee doesn't have a topping, I don't want to simply say "nil" on the label, I want the label to disappear and the other too labels to stay close to each other. I was thinking of something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    if thisFeatureIsAvailable == false {
        //Make specific label disappear, move other labels together.
    } else {
    //Load content for label.
    }

}
```

I also have set some AutoLayout constraints for the labels.

Thank you,

tiferrei

Comment: In that case you can adjust your constraints programmatically. Everything is described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Comment: I suggest you using `UIStackView`. It handles the constraints for you and is well suited for your purpose. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

Comment: I chose the other answer because it seems like the easiest approach to my problem, as I already have quite some stuff designed which would be a pain in the back to change to an `UIStackView`, but thanks a lot @user2215977, will use your method in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set auto constraints for the labels already, they best way would be to change the **width of the label you want to hide to 0**. This will take care if the rest effortlessly.